# NaNs produced in negative binomial regression when using dnbinom()

Tags: r, regression, modeling

I am using `dnbinom()` for writing the log-likelihood function and then estimate parameters using `mle2()` {bbmle} in R.

The problem is that I got 16 warnings for my negative binomial model, all of them NaNs produced like this one:

> 1: In dnbinom(y, mu = mu, size = k, log = TRUE) : NaNs produced

My code:

```
# data
x <- c(0.35,0.45,0.90,0.05,1.00,0.50,0.45,0.25,0.15,0.40,0.26,0.37,0.43,0.34,0.00,0.11,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.41,0.14,0.80,0.60,0.23,0.17,0.31,0.30,0.00,0.23,0.33,0.30,0.00,0.00)
y <- c(1,10,0,0,67,0,9,5,0,0,0,82,36,0,32,7,7,132,14,33,0,67,11,39,41,67,9,1,44,62,111,52,0)

# log-likelihood function
negbinglmLL = function(beta,gamma,k) { 
  mu= exp(beta+gamma*x)
  -sum(dnbinom(y,mu=mu, size=k, log=TRUE))
}

# maximum likelihood estimator
model <- mle2(negbinglmLL, start=list(beta=mean(y), gamma= 0, k=mean(y)^2/(var(y)-mean(y))))
```

What do these warnings mean, and if this is a serious problem how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not restricting the negative log-likelihood function from trying negative values of `k`.  This *probably* doesn't mess up your final answer, but it's always best to avoid these kinds of warnings if you can.  Two simple strategies:

- put a lower bound on `k` (switching to `method=L-BFGS-B`)
- fit the `k` parameter on the log scale, as follows:

```
negbinglmLL = function(beta,gamma,logk) { 
  mu= exp(beta+gamma*x)
  -sum(dnbinom(y,mu=mu, size=exp(logk), log=TRUE))
}

model <- mle2(negbinglmLL,
              start=list(beta=mean(y),
                         gamma= 0, 
                      logk=log(mean(y)^2/(var(y)-mean(y)))))
```

By the way, for simple problems like this you can use a formula-based shortcut as follows:

```
mle2(y~dnbinom(mu=exp(logmu),size=exp(logk)),
     parameters=list(logmu~x),
     start=list(logmu=0,logk=0),
     data=data.frame(x,y))
```

For this simple case `MASS::glm.nb` should also work perfectly well (but perhaps this is the simplest version of something that will get more complicated/beyond the scope of `glm.nb`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I decided to use your first alternative: model <- mle2(negbinglmLL, start=list(beta=mean(y), gamma= 0, k=mean(y)^2/(var(y)-mean(y))), method="L-BFGS-B", lower=c(beta=-Inf,gamma=-Inf,k=0), upper = c(beta=Inf,gamma=Inf,k=Inf))

Comment: The only problem is that when using method=L-BFGS-B, the standard errors of the coefficient are quite different from the ones obtained by using the glm.nb function. You were right, I am going to add terms to the log-like function so I am not going to use the glm.nb, but I was expecting on having similar results for the variance in this simplest case.

Comment: hmm, what do you mean by "quite different"?  Comparing `mle2` with `L-BFGS-B` and `glm.nb`, I get std errors of 0.445 vs 0.460 for the intercept, 0.266 vs 0.249 for the slope ... are those the magnitudes of the errors you're concerned about?  They seem "similar" ...

Comment: Yes, you are right values vary just a little, I supposed this is because of using different optim algorithms. I also noticed that when changing the initial values, coefficient outcomes also vary a little. I had to change my gamma initial value to whatever number different from 0, because the mle2 function was returning "Error in optim...". I am not sure why this is happening, zero for regressor coeficient seems like an appropiate initial value to start with. This is my first time using negative binomial, maybe this type of model is more sensitive to initial values.