# Trouble installing glmmadmb in R

Tags: r

I am having trouble installing glmmADMB package and hoping to get some help here. I've talked to people I know who uses R but we couldn't figure this out.

Looks like the error is about a symbol in the directory. However, the ' is included as a default naming convention in Windows and I can't seem to change the folder name. I name my computer Vanessa and it automatically give the user folder name "Vanessa's PC". [It might not due to this error, since I have ran some other codes that included this symbol in the command.] Any suggestions or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

This is the log I got:

> install.packages("glmmADMB", 
>   +                  repos=c("http://glmmadmb.r-forge.r-project.org/repos",
>   +                          getOption("repos")),
>   +                  type="source")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Vanessa's PC/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   trying URL 'http://glmmadmb.r-forge.r-project.org/repos/src/contrib/glmmADMB_0.8.3.3.tar.gz'
>   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 9391177 bytes (9.0 MB)
>   downloaded 9.0 MB

- installing *source* package 'glmmADMB' ...
  ** R
  ** data
  *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
  ** inst
  ** preparing package for lazy loading
  Warning: package 'MASS' was built under R version 3.4.4
  ** help
  *** installing help indices
  ** building package indices
  ** installing vignettes
  ** testing if installed package can be loaded
  *** arch - i386
  Error: unexpected symbol in "tools:::.test_load_package('glmmADMB', 'C:/Users/Vanessa's"
  Execution halted
  *** arch - x64
  Error: unexpected symbol in "tools:::.test_load_package('glmmADMB', 'C:/Users/Vanessa's"
  Execution halted
  ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
- removing 'C:/Users/Vanessa's PC/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/glmmADMB'
  Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Vanessa's PC\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\VANESSA'S~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2piXfe/downloaded_packages/glmmADMB_0.8.3.3.tar.gz' had status 1
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘glmmADMB’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\Vanessa's PC\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2piXfe\downloaded_packages’

Comment: (1) I'm pretty sure that your problem does indeed from the apostrophe/single quote in your path name; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47478890/cant-install-tidyverse-unexpected-symbol-in-hms (unanswered, I made the same comment there) ...

Comment: (2) the problem is in installing packages from source. If you're willing to switch to the `glmmTMB` package, which is available directly from CRAN (and works as well as or better than `glmmADMB` anyway), that would probably solve your problem ...

Comment: (3) are you able to install any other packages from source?

Comment: Thanks! I've only installed package that is available in CRAN before. This is the first package I try to install from source. I am installing this because I want to use the negative binomial distribution function. I used to use MASS to run negative binomial distribution, but MASS would not run - giving me no coefficient error. Can glmmTMB run negative binomial distribution?

Comment: Yes, `glmmTMB` can handle negative binomial distributions. (You could also post a question that describes your problems with `MASS::glm.nb`; `bbmle::mle2` can also be used for these problems, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40191202/nans-produced-in-negative-binomial-regression-when-using-dnbinom

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the `devtools` package first and then installing `glmmADMB` directly from the development version on GitHub:

```
> library(devtools)
> devtools::install_github("bbolker/glmmadmb")
Downloading GitHub repo bbolker/glmmadmb@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/bbolker/glmmadmb/zipball/master
Installing glmmADMB
Installing 1 package: R2admb
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 
'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/R2admb_0.7.16.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 505317 bytes (493 KB)
downloaded 493 KB

package ‘R2admb’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4WWJZp\downloaded_packages
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ 
--no-save -- no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
"C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp4WWJZp/devtools28d0200a7e9b/bbolker- 
glmmadmb-ac75f73"  \
 --library="C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.4" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'glmmADMB' ...
....

> library(glmmADMB)
Loading required package: MASS

Attaching package: ‘glmmADMB’

The following object is masked from ‘package:MASS’:

    stepAIC

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    step
```

Comment: this probably doesn't resolve OP's issue, because you don't have a single-quote in your path name ...

Comment: Thanks mysteRious. I tried installing devtools first and then glmmadmb package. Still giving the same error. Ben Bolker is right, its due to single-quote in my path.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
install.packages("R2admb")

install.packages("glmmADMB", 
    repos=c("http://glmmadmb.r-forge.r-project.org/repos",
            getOption("repos")),
    type="source")

library(glmmADMB)
```